# SSL Connection problems when using https for rubygems

Tags: ruby, ssl

Suddenly, I can only install gems after doing

```
> gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/
> gem sources --add http://rubygems.org/
```

with source being https, the error is `Error fetching https://rubygems.org/:
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

However, I updated my certificates and `rvm osx-ssl-certs status all` returns

```
Certificates for /opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
```

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, Ruby 2.3.0, RVM 1.29.0, openssl 1.0.11

Answer (score 0):

[for anyone else experiencing this, here is a solution that helped me](https://github.com/tenex/rails-assets/issues/239#issuecomment-87108900)

```
$ brew update && brew install openssl
$ cd /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
$ curl -O http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
$ mv cacert.pem cert.pem
$ /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash
```